# Firebase rules for user list best practice?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Somehow I still have a understanding problem with firebase rules and need some input from you guys.

Lets say I have a user node with all my users. Each user contain sub-nodes for things like email, name, phone etc.

My basic firebase rule says now that only the user with the correct id can edit/write/read in his own node. This works all fine. But now I do have situations like another user search for a friend and there for I need to search for example in all my users for a name or email BUT since my rule does not allow to read userdata except if the user is the owner of his own data I dont know how to solve this. I cant use a rule to give every authenticated user READ rights for the other users data BUT I still would like to search for example for a email address in the other users data. This confuses me all a lot.

The only thing I can think of is to run parallel a complete separated list with something like public informations and keep the rule that everybody can read (not write) in this list. BUT THEN again I have the issue that somebody could easy access my entire user-list (emails for example) if I keep them inside the public list.

I would be happy if somebody can point me into the right direction. I have no idea where to start to set this up from the start correct.

What is the best approach to do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey I'm not a pro or affiliated with Firebase. But as I have encountered same type of problems I share my thoughts with you.

1. I don't think allowing users to search others based on emails stored in a Firebase node and directly from client side is entirely safe. Searching based on somethign like userName is ok because it is scoped to your app.
2. If you must, then I would either make it a 2 step process using Firebase functions (which you can put another layer of security check in there also no user is directly reading from database) or introduce other parameters that all need to pass for a successful query. Something like a temporary unique id that expires after awhile.
3. If you still want to share emails, you can store user's sensitive information in a separate node and only save what you really need to expose to others in a public node which can still have some security rules protecting it form access of someone who is not logged in, for instance and you map the emails by UIDs.

Just some thoughts.

EDITS

1. You can provide a way for users to be able to search others by username (similar to instagram for instance.) and in firebase you only have to connect each username with their UID. So people can find each other via username. Imagine this in firebase (you can do the same of emails so a person making request need to know an email to get UID not the other way) :

   user_names : {
         alice_d: UID, 
         bob_ross: UID, 
         ....
   }

You can later search for any user name without exposing others simply by using .equalTo() in your query or run more complex queries via FireStore (I am new to it too) or using a search system that has your data indexed already like Algolia.

2. Facebook provides further information such as list of friends if you app is approved so you can always use that list to suggest friends granted that users have logged in by Facebook O'auth and your app has the priviledge to see friends lists.
3. See [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint) for how to verify a user making https requests in Firebase functions. In your function you can do the search and only return what is safe back to the client. (keep in mind the speed might be an issue unless your function is running frequently). And for making the request from client side, you do something like this.

   ```
   _makeRequest: function() {
   this.user.getIdToken().then(function(token) {
     //token is a long string JWT token used to identify the user to a Firebase service.
   var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

   req.onload = function() {
   /*you return the result in your function*/
   if (JSON.parse(req.responseText).rslt === "SUCCESS") {

   }
   }.bind(this);

   req.onerror = function() {

   }.bind(this);

   /*attaching location key*/
   req.open('GET', 'https://us-central1-rest-of-function-address-found-in-
   firebase-functions', true);
   req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
   req.send();
   ```

   }

You can also make this happen by writing something to database and have a function to run onCreate(), see here if you need more info on [Firebase functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. I understand what you are saying and agree. I basically search for a way to let users search for their friends like many apps do. How can I accomplish this without the option to let users search for names and/or emails. I thought about a external php which has admin rights to search inside the firebase user node. Like this you can maximum access the php script with your user id and search for specific email if you know the email but you can never list the entire tree or even find a email which you dont know already.

Comment: I would be glad if I could help. Firebase functions provide a great way for achieving that. I think searching by username is best as it is not a personal information that could compromise privacy and also your users can always change their user name as long as it is unique. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow any user to find any other user by their email address, that means that users must be able to read email addresses. If you don't want them to be able to read the full profiles, you'll want to set up an extra data structure that maps email addresses to UIDs:

```
emails: {
  "theeben@domain,com": "uid5601401",
  "puf@theotherdomain,com": "uid209103"
}
```

With this structure you're only exposing the email addresses.

But to be honest, that is still exposing quite some information about all users. Nowadays, I'd consider implementing the search using Cloud Functions for Firebase. That way your API is a `function findUser(email): uid` type function, exposing only the minimal information.

Comment: Thank you Frank, I think I go with an external php script like I described above.